# JavaScript Canvas check if rectangle include rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have two array with object.
Example:

```
var boxes = [],
    coins = [],
    k = 0;

boxes.push({
    x: 300,
    y: 350,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

for (k; k < 30; k++) {
    coins.push({
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 4) + 4) * 100,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1) * 100,
        width:25,
        height:25
    });
}
```

After that I use `for` for draw those things. The problem is that sometimes the coins will drawn in boxes. 
How to check if coins are in boxes range?
I was thinking about calculating the square boxes and coins but I have no idea how to finish that.

```
var i = 0,
    j = 0;

for (i; i < coins.length; i++) {
    for (j; j < boxes.length; j++) {

        if (boxes[j].x + boxes[j].width /* something */ coins[i].x + coins[i].width && boxes[j].y + boxes[j].height /* something */ coins[i].y + coins[i].height) {
            /* do nothing */
        } else { 
            ctx.fillRect(coins[i].x, coins[i].y, coins[i].width, coins[i].height);
        }

    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to finish that? Or maybe there is any other way?
I can use only pure JavaScript.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your `for` loops are uniformly incorrect. You need to initialize the iterator variables, like `for (var k = 0; k < 30; k++)` - also declare them correctly with `var`

Comment: @Pointy oops, my mistake. But it's only here, in my code there is declaration. I will fix it here.

Comment: Why did you write `(10 - 4)` instead of `6`. Is it the same or am I missing something? I tried to duplicate your code in a visual programming environment but the coins and boxes do not seem to overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the **if condition** to get a hit:

```
if (
    (boxes[j].x < (coins[i].x + coins[i].width) &&  (boxes[j].x + boxes[j].width) > coins[i].x) &&
    (boxes[j].y < (coins[i].y + coins[i].height) &&  (boxes[j].y + boxes[j].height) > coins[i].y)
) {
    /* HIT - Do nothing */
} else {
    /* No Hit - Draw the coin */
}
```

I didn't test it, but I'm sure it works ...

---

**EDIT:**

By the way, I noticed you are not re-setting `i` and `j` var in the `for` loops, you should do that at least with the second loop (`j`), otherwise loop it will not work.

```
for (i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
```

Comment: I think you still need a condition for when a box is inside the other one (one box being smaller than the other). You write box collision code differently than I do so it makes my head hurt.

Comment: @asimes this method is pretty simple ... first line > x/width validation, second line y/height validation.
And it doesn't need to know if one box is smaller than other, because it tests each box separately. So it is totaly independent from the box/coin sizes

Comment: I mean when `(b.x < c.x && c.x+c.width < b.x+b.width)`. In other words, the coin being smaller than the box matters because it fits inside of the box.

Comment: @asimes I understood your example, but mine stills validating that situation. Just try it [with a draw, like I did :)]

Comment: I put two objects (real ones) in front of myself I tried it every way I could think of. You are right, it does work, I guess I was just surprised box collision could be that short to write. +1!

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I've been doing box collisions like this since ever. I'm glad you understand it, and approved it :)